# How can I change current working directory in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: directory, settings, sublimetext3, preferences, cwd

Whenever I open a script (Python or R), I want Sublime automatically changes the current working directory to the path of that file. Is it possible?

I added the setting `"working_dir": "$file_path",` to Sublime preferences but it doesn't help.

Comment: That's a build system setting; it won't do anything in the general preferences. If your intention is to make sure that your python script runs with it's working directory the same as where it's located, you need to add that line to the default python build file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. Here is what I did:

1. Install Sublime Text 3 package `PackageResourceViewer`
2. Open Command Palette, search for `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
3. Browse to `Python` resource then open `Python.sublime-build`
4. Remove the default line `"shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",`
5. Add the following 2 lines:

   `"cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],`

   `"working_dir": "$file_path",`
6. Alternately, you can replace the above 2 lines by:

   `"shell_cmd": "cd $file_path; python -u \"$file\""`

Do the same thing for `R` or other build resources if you want Sublime Text 3 automatically change the current working directory in accordance with the active scripts' path.

Comment: as a third option. leaving shell_cmd as it is and just adding the working_dir to the dictionary worked for me.  The approach of trying to use "cd" within the command failed though, saying "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." (on Windows).  Not clear why as I had the correct path.  working_dir seems like the better way to do in anyhow.

Comment: I worked on Unix based system (Mac OSX) and that's why it worked. In Windows, you should change "cd" to "dir", I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the python console using the Show Console command in View menu, and then type

```
import os
os.chdir('/my/directory')
```

It changes the working directory for the Sublime Text process and whatever process it spawns.

Comment: This is not a correct solution for the question which requires Sublime change the directory automatically

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: You know the console opens with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>. When I use the combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> it's directly chosing the current file path. And this way is something you have to do every single time you open sublime text.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, plus if i wanted to import a module, it would always return module not found. 
**To fix this:** I change the first line of my python.sublime-build file to what i have below

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "cd $file_path; python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
{
    "env": "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
    ],
    "variants":
}
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "python -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        }
    ]
}
```

Being cuper curious, i wanted to know **why** this was happening, so after doing more investigations about my os, ran:

```
import os

for k, v in os.environ.items():
    print(k, v)
print(os.getcwd())
```

which returns a dictionary of my environment variables and their values, including 2 that answered my questions in the build results `PWD` and `OLDPWD`:

```
PWD /Users/<myname>/code
OLDPWD /Users/<myname>/code/code_py
...
[Finished 0.0ms]
...
[shell_cmd: cd /Users/<myname>/code/code_py; python -u "/Users/<myname>/code/code_py/YT-tutorials.py"]
...
```

AHA!
because i previously added `cd $HOME/code` my ~/.bash_profile, so every time i would build (command+B) in sublime with python, my shell profile would **change directories behind the scenes** and move me into my ~/code directory. 
Now, after changing the python.sublime-build file as mentioned above changed this build behavior has been fixed -- & i hope this helps you too!